# Grouping by half hour slots doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

Following on from [this question's answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839052/group-by-hour-but-show-another-field), I have tried to get my half hour slot groupings to work, but for whatever reason, it isn't numbering the rows as either 1 or 2 respectively, depending on whether the minutes are greater or smaller than 30.

Can anyone give me some clues as to where I've gone wrong?

```
select Deal, Price
from (select md.*,
            row_number() over (partition by case when (datepart(minute, Deal) < 30) then 1 else 2 end
                               order by Deal desc) as seqnum
      from MyData md
      where Product = 'XXXXX' AND
            CAST(Deal AS Date) = '2013-09-04'
     ) md
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `seqnum` column actually goes from 1 to N, instead of being 1,2 whether it is below or over 30 mins in the `Deal` field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does any value containing null for minute?

Comment: Try partition by case when (datepart(isnull(minute,0), Deal) < 30

Comment: @KayNelson yes there will be 0 values for minute, unfortunately

Comment: @KayNelson adding `isnull` as you showed gives me this: Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.

Comment: Wait, im not awake yet.  (datepart(minute, isnull(Deal,Now())) < 30

Comment: If deal is of value null, it will now give the currect time and should give 0 in minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything to the results.  `Deal` is a `DateTime` field, FYI

Comment: Does deal Always have a datetime value and never null?

Comment: @KayNelson it always has a value, however, the minutes may be `00`.

Comment: Still, even if it was working, that query would return all groups that were in XX:00-XX:29.99.. for every hour of the day. Is that really what you want? You could just be grouping by the the Date, the Hour, and Minutes < 30

Comment: @OGHaza well, the problem I'm trying to solve is being able to get a price at the beginning of a 30 min slot, and at the end of a 30 slot. To do that, I thought splitting things into 30 min slots would be logical.

Comment: ah, you're right, that does make sense, I was misreading the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because SeqNum is not meant to be 1 or 2 in that query. Sequence number is the row number when you partition the data based on that 1 or 2 value. This means that every value with mins < 30 is split into a set, and then ordered by Deal they are numbered from 1 to N. Then the same is done for Deal >= 30.

To do what you want to do you should partition by the Date, and the Hour, as well as your 1 or 2 value so that then the records for each individual half hour are split into sets and numbered, that way SeqNum = 1 for the first record in each half hour.

Try changing your seqnum to:

```
row_number() over (partition by 
              CAST(Deal AS DATE)
            , DATEPART(HOUR, Deal)
            , case when (datepart(minute, Deal) < 30) then 1 else 2 end
                               order by Deal ASC) 
            as seqnum
```

Only split into so many lines for readability on here.

To show you what sequence number is doing, try running:

```
select md.*
    ,CAST(Deal AS DATE) AS [Date]
    ,DATEPART(HOUR, Deal) AS [Hour]
    ,case when (datepart(minute, Deal) < 30) then 1 else 2 END AS [WhichHalf]
    ,row_number() over (partition by 
              CAST(Deal AS DATE)
            , DATEPART(HOUR, Deal)
            , case when (datepart(minute, Deal) < 30) then 1 else 2 end
                               order by Deal ASC) 
            as seqnum
from MyData md
where Product = 'XXXXX' AND
    CAST(Deal AS Date) = '2013-09-04'
ORDER BY Deal
```

Hopefully you've got enough data for it to be obvious what the sequence number is doing there. (A Record with Deal=12:01 might get numbered SeqNum=1, then every record after that would be numbered 2,3,4... until it got past 12:30 at which point it will reset to 1 again)

Comment: Ok, I did that and it has `2013-09-04 14:54:02.000` in the results.

Comment: Try just running the inner query, and order it by Deal. What do the seqnums look like?

Comment: just updated my answer, it should have been ordering by deal ASC (so that values earliest in the half hour are seqnum=1)

Comment: There's still the `09:44:00` dealtime in the 1 seqnums. Hmmm

Comment: Yes but SeqNum = 1 does not mean first half hour. It means 1st record in any half hour. 9:44 will be the first record in the 9:30-9:59 range.

Comment: oh I'm apparently misunderstanding how this is supposed to work :/

Comment: so then `where seqnum = 1;` is really the wrong condition to select all within the first 30 min range?

Comment: SeqNum = 1 Refers to the first record in the PARTITION. So the first record in any half hour. Which if you want the first price from the half hour is probably the record you want. Updating answer now.

Comment: No problem, if you also want last price in a half hour - as I think you said in the other question, do the same PARTITION BY but with ORDER BY Deal DESC